# Module 'pip._internal.download' has no attribute 'is_file_url'

Tags: python, pip

after upgrade to pip-19.3.1

```
 pip-compile requirements.in
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip-compile", line 7, in <module>
    from piptools.scripts.compile import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/piptools/scripts/compile.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .._compat import install_req_from_line, parse_requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/piptools/_compat/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .pip_compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/piptools/_compat/pip_compat.py", line 32, in <module>
    is_file_url = do_import("download", "is_file_url")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/piptools/_compat/pip_compat.py", line 24, in do_import
    return getattr(imported, package)
AttributeError: module 'pip._internal.download' has no attribute 'is_file_url'
```

Comment: `pip-tools>=4.2.0 is compatible with pip>=19.3. Better to upgrade pip-tools` as reported [here](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/981#issuecomment-554181234)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip-compile` and the `pip-tools` package that provide it might *sound* like actual parts of `pip`, but they're actually third-party things that abuse the `pip` internals in ways that are explicitly unsupported and subject to no backward compatibility guarantees.

That means that whenever `pip` itself gets a new version, there's a pretty decent chance that `pip-tools` and `pip-compile` (and anything else that reaches into `pip`'s guts) will abruptly stop working until the `pip-tools` developers adjust things. When that happens, you have to update `pip-tools` (if a fix is available), downdate `pip` (if `pip-tools` doesn't have a fix available yet), or just stop using `pip-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

fixed after

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip-tools
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be running `pip` with `sudo`. Use a virtualenv.